# Cannot connect to SQL Server database on Nodejs EC2 server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running a node server. The pages and routes render fine on the frontend, but when I do anything that requires a call to the api it says failed to connect to XX.XX.X.XXX:1433 (which is my SQL Server database). When I run the app locally (not inside the EC2 instance) it works just fine and connects to the DB. Btw, my local computer is NOT where the SQL Server database is being hosted.

What could the issue be on the instance?

EDIT: TCP is enabled and the Browser part is running in the SQL manager.

EDIT2:This is the error I get every time my EC2 app makes an api call to te database:
`ConnectionError: Failed to connect to XX.XX.X.XXX:1433 in 15000ms`
But when I do the dame thing on the app from its development computer on localhost it works just fine.

Comment: Where is the database in relation to the EC2 instance -- is it on the same instance, or on another EC2 instance in the same VPC, or perhaps on an Amazon RDS database? Please Edit your question to include these details. Also, if the database is on a separate server, please include details of your Security Group settings and tell us whether you connect via a public IP address, private IP address or DNS name.

Comment: The database is not an an EC2 instance or any AWS system. I think I am connecting to it through the IP of the IIS server that it is on.

Comment: So you are saying that your database is publicly accessible on the Internet and you are connecting to its Public IP address? What is the configuration of the Outbound Rules in the Security Group associated with the EC2 instance running your node server?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, it looks like this is a network connectivity problem.  Can you ping the DB server?

```
ping xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Second, can you telnet to the port?

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 1433
```

My guess is that both of these will fail.  So, the question is, why?

Some things to consider:

- Is the database server on the public internet?  (I hope not, for security reasons.)
- Is your client computer on the public internet?
- What is the network access path to get from your client machine to the DB server?  VPN tunnel?  SSLVPN connection?  Something else?

I don't have a specific solution for you, but hopefully I gave you some ideas as to where to look.  The problem is (almost certainly) not a database problem, but a network connectivity issue.

Comment: Could it be that I have to open the 1433 port on the EC2 instance security for the client app?

Comment: Absolutely.  Port 1433 definitely needs to be opened if you want to connect to it.

Comment: I tried the ping and telnet from my home computer neither worked